# How do I make my bashRC source permanent?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

When I make my bashRC file with nano `~/.bashrc`. 
With only one alias:

```
alias c="clear"
```

I only can use the alias if I enter `source ~/.bashrc` or use `. ~/.bashr`, but I want this source to carry over to new terminal windows. Is there away to make this the default source? Or is there another way to make the `bashrc` permanent?

Comment: `.bashrc` is automatically sourced into interactive terminals that are not also login terminals. On MacOS, new tabs are login terminals, so they run `~/.bash_profile` instead. Easy answer is to `source ~/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: That said, note that this is generally a question for [unix.se], and off-topic here. Bash questions can definitely be topical if you're asking for help writing a script, but configuring an interactive terminal is in no way an act "unique to software development".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add it to .bash_profile.

.bashrc is for noninteractive logins

if you are opening a new window and logging in manually you need to add it to .bash_profile

Comment: Note the bullet point in the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions* in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) about questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before", and also the one about questions which "are not about programming as [defined in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: Also, it's flatly wrong that `.bashrc` is "for noninteractive logins". It's for *interactive*, non-login shells. The only dotfiles executed for noninteractive shells is that named in the environment variable `BASH_ENV` (if it exists and the shell is bash), or `ENV` (for baseline-POSIX-compatible shells, or bash in POSIX mode).

Comment: *".bashrc is for noninteractive logins"* -- This is NOT true.